# Values does not fall within expected range when bind data from MongoDB in UWP using C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, uwp

I am trying to display the data from MongoDB to GridView in my UWP app. But I encountered this error:

> Value does not fall within expected range

The error happens at `Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ItemsControl.put_ItemSource(Object value)`
What am I doing wrong in the code?

Here is my Sample Data which stored inside MongoDB that need to be displayed:

```
_id:ObjectId("59d33acc050bad03bcbd7094")

Timestamp:2017-10-03 15:22:51.828

ID:"915114910253764608"

Content:"как пел Cypress Hill Some people tell me that I need help"

DateCreated:2015-09-01 00:00:00.000

UserID:"3513470296"

Username:"Sapsan"
```

Here is my XAML Code:

```
<Page
x:Class="MyApp.viewrecord"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:MyApp"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">
<RelativePanel x:Name="Root" Background="Black">
    <Image x:Name="BackgroundImage" Source="ms-appx:///Assets/recordback.jpg"
           RelativePanel.AlignBottomWithPanel="True"
           RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
           RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True"
           RelativePanel.AlignTopWithPanel="True"
           Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
    <GridView ItemsSource="x:Bind data" x:Name="DataGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="578" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1194" Margin="139,219,-1333,-787" Opacity="0.2" FontFamily="Rockwell" FontSize="20" Background="White"/>
    <Border BorderBrush="#FF000000" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" CornerRadius="0,0,0,0" Margin="-2,1,-1437,-135" Opacity="0.3" Background="White"/>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="52" Text="View Data That Stored Inside The Database" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="971" Margin="380,65,-1289.182,-97" FontFamily="Rockwell" FontSize="36" Foreground="White"/>
</RelativePanel>
```

Here is my class for data binding:

```
public class data
{
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public string UserID { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
}
```

This is my code for data binding in the method:

```
private async void Display()
    {
        try
        {
            MongoClient client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost");
            var database = client.GetDatabase("TrainData");
            var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("Sample3");
            DataTable data = new DataTable();
            var filter = new BsonDocument();
            using (var cursor = await collection.FindAsync(filter))
            {
                while (await cursor.MoveNextAsync())
                {
                    var document = cursor.Current;

                    data.Columns.Add("Timestamp", typeof(DateTime));
                    data.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(string));
                    data.Columns.Add("Content", typeof(string));
                    data.Columns.Add("DateCreated", typeof(DateTime));
                    data.Columns.Add("UserID", typeof(string));
                    data.Columns.Add("Username", typeof(string));

                    foreach (var item in document)
                    {
                        data.Rows.Add(item["Timestamp"], item["ID"], item["Content"],item["DateCreated"],item["UserID"], item["Username"]);
                    }
                }
                DataGrid.ItemsSource = data;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageDialog messagebox = new MessageDialog("Display Data Error: "+ex);
            await messagebox.ShowAsync();
        }
    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: Timestamp or DateCreated columns can cause this problem. you probably have out of range values.

Comment: Both of their format is YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00, is this not the format of DateTime data type? If I change it to string will it read as well?

Comment: Same result if I change both of the data type to string

Comment: could you add sample data to the question?

Comment: @sarslan Yes sure I have added the sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the bound object works for the dependency property.  In this case, the `ItemsControl.ItemsSource` property requires the object to implement one of the following interfaces:

.NET - `IEnumerable<Object>` or `IEnumerable`

C++/WinRT - `IVector<IInspectable>` or `IBindableObservableVector`

C++/CX - `IIterable<IInspectable>` or `IBindableIterable`

If you're sure that `GridView` is the control you what to use to display your data, you might create a `List<data>`, bind the ItemsSource to that and set the ItemTemplate to define how to display each data object.

See the [ItemsControl documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource?view=winrt-22621) for more info.